# Python: Read and write text file with header and numeric columns

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a text file which has some header lines and some columns (numbers).
I want to read this file skipping the header,then select some columns and
write them in a new file using a Python script.

For example, lets call the data below `in_table.txt`.
I want to skip the header (also the blank lines),
then select the first and fourth columns (only the numeric values)
and save them in a new file `out_table.txt` without headers, just numbers.
How can I do that using a Python script?

many thanks!!

in_table.txt:

```
hline1 hline1 hline1
hline2 hline2 hline2

hline3 hline3 hline3

par1  par2  par3  par4  par5
1.    10.   100.  1000. 10000.
2.    20.   200.  2000. 20000.
3.    30.   300.  3000. 30000.
4.    40.   400.  4000. 40000.
5.    50.   500.  5000. 50000.
```

.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sticking with space delimiters use

```
with open('in_table.txt') as f:
    # Iterate through the file until the table starts
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('------'):
            break
    # Read the rest of the data, using spaces to split. 
    data = [r.split() for r in f]

with open('out_file.csv', 'w') as of:
    for r in data:
        # Write only column 0 and 2 (re: 0-indexing)
        of.write('%s, %s\n'%(r[0], r[2]))
```

**CSV**

If you delimit with commas you could probably pythons inbuilt `csv` library

```
import csv 
with open('in_table.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('------'):
            break
    data = [r for r in csv.reader(f)]

with open('out_file.csv', 'w') as of:
    for r in data:
        of.write('%s, %s\n'%(r[0], r[2]))
```

or perhaps more concisely

```
import csv 
with open('in_table.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('------'):
            break  
    data = [r[0]+r[2] for r in csv.reader(f)]

wrt = csv.writer(open('out_file.csv', 'w'))
wrt.writerows(data)
```